# Testing PersonFirstName class as a Value Object

Tags: c#, design-patterns, unit-testing

For [reference](http://deviq.com/value-object/):

> A Value Object is an immutable type that is distinguishable only by the state of its properties. That is, unlike an Entity, which has a unique identifier and remains distinct even if its properties are otherwise identical, two Value Objects with the exact same properties can be considered equal.

Please see the code below:

```
public class PersonFirstName
{
    //public string FirstName { get; set; }

    private string _firstName;

    public PersonFirstName(string firstName)
    {
        if (firstName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Surname");
        if (!PersonFirstName.IsValid(firstName))
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid value.", "Surname");
        this._firstName = firstName;
        FirstName = firstName;
    }

    public PersonFirstName() //for NHibernate
    {
    }

    public static bool IsValid(string candidate)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(candidate))
            return false;
        if (candidate.Length > 255)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        private set 
        {
            _firstName = value; 
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        PersonFirstName PersonFirstName = obj as PersonFirstName;
        if (ReferenceEquals(PersonFirstName, null))
            return false;
        return _firstName == PersonFirstName.FirstName;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _firstName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and the Unit Test below:

```
[Test]
public void Domain_FirstNameValue_ValueObjectCreated()
{
    //Arrange
    var PersonFirstName1 = new PersonFirstName("Ian");
    var PersonFirstName2 = new PersonFirstName("Ian");
    //Act
    var firstNameCompareResult = PersonFirstName1.Equals(PersonFirstName2);
    //Assert
    Assert.True(firstNameCompareResult);
}
```

I would be grateful for comments on the quality of this test.

Comment: Your last edit invalidated the existing answer. [Please don't do that.](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2375/52915)

Comment: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @AdrianIftode I think, this link of yours is great on its own, but if only you wrote an answer based on that!..

Answer (score 5):

A few notes:

- The argument exceptions contain an incorrect parameter name (`"Surname"`). Use `nameof(firstName)` instead: this allows the compiler to verify that you're referencing an existing identifier, and the refactoring tools of your IDE can automatically update it when you rename that parameter.
- Why are you setting both `this._firstName` and `FirstName` in the constructor? That's doing double work.
- A read-only automatic property seems appropriate here: `public string FirstName { get; }`. This can only be assigned within a constructor, similar to `readonly` fields, and doesn't require you to explicitly create a backing field.
- I see a disabled property with a public setter. If it wasn't disabled, then `FirstName` instances could not guarantee that their `GetHashCode` would always return the same value. That could lead to subtle bugs such as failing dictionary lookups, so you did well to make your class immutable.
- You may want to implement `IEquatable<T>`. It's not a replacement for `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, but it lets you provide a strongly-typed equality check, which can prevent unnecessary type-checks or boxing/unboxing, and it clearly signals intent. Likewise, if you need to order or sort these first-names, take a look at `IComparable` and `IComparable<T>`.
- Why does `IsValid` not allow names longer than 255 characters? If there's a good reason for that, then why isn't it documented? And does that restriction always apply, or only in a certain context? And is a simple `false` or `ArgumentException` sufficient for the caller, or do they need to distinguish between different validation failures?
- The test method is incorrectly named: according to the name, it's testing object creation, but it's actually testing equality. `Domain_EqualFirstNameValues_Equals` would be more accurate.
- `Assert.True` has an overload that accepts a failure message. A good message (perhaps including the values that are involved) can make it easier to determine why a test is failing.

Answer (score 3):

I would also add a "sanity check" test which verifies that the two names are different, `false` is returned:

```
public void Domain_FirstNameValue_ValueObjectCreated()
{
    //Arrange
    var PersonFirstName1 = new PersonFirstName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    var PersonFirstName2 = new PersonFirstName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    //Act
    var firstNameCompareResult = PersonFirstName1.Equals(PersonFirstName2);
    //Assert
    Assert.False(firstNameCompareResult);
}
```

Otherwise your test can pass with a degenerate implementation of `Equals`:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return true;
}
```

Granted in this case you'd probably spot it but the principle is to make sure your test result isn't a false positive :)

I'd also try to remove the hardcoded values from the test, just to ensure you don't run into the same issues.

e.g.

```
public void Domain_FirstNameValue_ValueObjectCreated()
{
    //Arrange
    var name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var PersonFirstName1 = new PersonFirstName(name);
    var PersonFirstName2 = new PersonFirstName(name);
    //Act
    var firstNameCompareResult = PersonFirstName1.Equals(PersonFirstName2);
    //Assert
    Assert.True(firstNameCompareResult);
}
```

With both this and the sanity check test, it's much less likely that any degenerate implementation can pass both.

Also in the implementation itself  I'd change `if (ReferenceEquals)` to just a plain null check - this is to indicate that the object passed is not an instance of `PersonFirstName` as opposed to if it's a null reference in general.

e.g.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var PersonFirstName = obj as PersonFirstName;
    if (PersonFirstName == null) return false;
    return _firstName == PersonFirstName.FirstName;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The restriction on 255 characters is probably too weak. In MySQL for example, a `VARCHAR(255)` field is 255 *bytes* long, not 255 *characters*. If you ever want to save non-English names, the limit may be as small as 63 characters since the UTF-8 encoding for emojis (among others) needs 4 bytes per character.

Local variable names usually start with a lowercase letter.